# How close can we get C++ to C#'s ease of use? Reopen?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, question-quality

I've reworded [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809640/how-close-can-we-get-c-to-cs-ease-of-use). First of all do we consider it better, ie more focused? If not how can I get it more focused for approval?  I want to use Stack Overflow as for me it's the best place to ask this kind of question because of the knowledgeable people who use the site.

Comment: I still feel this might be "not constructive". Perhaps not because of the question you're asking, but because of the answers you're most likely to get. You seem to want to make C++ into something it's not. And the answers given already address some of your motivations to do so by showing you how to address them in the C++ way. I would not vote for it to be reopened, but that's just me.

Comment: I'm not trying to make C++ into something its not: I'm using the language as it is hence the compile-able C++ code snippet!  Its not my fault there are some users out there which are going to focus on the tit for tat argument of which language is 'best'.

Comment: @user176168 It's very much your fault some users will focus on “which language is best”, because that's featured prominently in your question.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you don't mean to start an argument. The argument is built in. This is exactly like code style wars in the sense.

Comment: Now you'll have to undelete it first.

Comment: Well this is great my question has been deleted!  I'm a C++ programmer and personally don't see anything argumentative in that question.  C# has some better features and ease of use is one of them that's why Microsoft wrote it surely?  However I would have reworded the title if that would have calmed everybody down.  But I seem to have been denied that now: is there anyway to get a question undeleted?  Or at least if someone could send me the text of question and I can go else where to ask it.

Answer (score 10):

Ok, right off the bat I admit I haven't read your whole question, and I'm neither a C++ programmer nor a C# programmer.

Your title is “How close can we get C++ to C#'s ease of use?”. The first thing you need to do is change this. A title like this makes me think I'm going to read a rant against C++. Hey, I'm not really adverse to rants against C++, but a Stack Overflow question is not the place for them. Your title already puts the reader into an unsympathetic frame of mind.

Then it's not just a matter of fixing the title, because the title seems to reflect the body well. The body is a big wall of text, and my eyes glazed over well before I could understand what the question was about. Ok, so I'm not in the intended audience of the question. Nonetheless, you really need to work on this question. I think there is some specific feature that you'd like to provide in C++ as a library, and that feature is part of the C# language, but I can't figure out what. So:

Forget anything about “ease of use”. Forget anything about C#: make your question accessible to people who know C++ well and C# not at all. Describe what you want to achieve. **Be precise**. If you want “C++ to behave more like C#”, get a C# compiler. If what you want is to do something in C++, concentrate on telling us what it is.

Comment: I think the concern expressed here about the title is spot-on. It's possible that I'm the opposite from you and fall *directly* into the target audience (as someone who uses both C# and C++ regularly) but I think the *body* of the question is actually asking a reasonable, answerable question. They want to know how to implement some of the features of C# that they like in C++. There's nothing wrong with that question, and I think that's evident by reading the answers it had received. People just don't read beyond the title, and that's less their fault than the asker's.